# Remove/Convert numbers to handle as FLOAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, excel

I have numbers with thousands separator and commas (exported out an Excel csv) which I want to insert into an table (more exact a column) which is `FLOAT`. Now the problem is that the numbers are not imported the right way.

For example, the number (column name is `cash`) in the Excel file is `14.142,99` and the entry in the table (`FLOAT` column name is `cash`, too) is `14.142`

At the moment I bypass the problem by define the column as `VARCHAR` and import it then (then the entries are correct): but what's the query I can change the numbers into correct form and change the format of the column from `VARCHAR` to `FLOAT`?

Tried this already, but it´s not working correctly:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET cash = FORMAT(cash, 2, 'de_DE');

ALTER TABLE Table1 
    MODIFY COLUMN cash FLOAT;
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: A tangent to your original question, but please do NOT use FLOAT for values that you expect to be precise.  You should use DECIMAL instead to avoid floating point errors.  Especially applicable to currency.  Regarding your actual question, please can you provide an sqlfiddle example showing your problem including what you are expecting.  "Not working correctly" is imprecise.  It's worth noting that FORMAT exists to convert numberst ot strings rather than strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column contains a de_DE formatted number, i.e. `14.142,99` and your expected is `14142.99`, then I would suggest the following

```
UPDATE Table1 
    SET cash = REPLACE( REPLACE( cash , '.' , '' ) , ',' , '.' );

ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY COLUMN cash DECIMAL( 10 , 2 );
```

As per my comment, I would suggest never using `FLOAT` for storing currency opting instead for a precise data type.  This would be either `DECIMAL` or `INTEGER` depending on precision required.